# Does using part of a usability questionnaire diminish its validity?

Tags: usability, surveys, quantitative-analysis, scale, questionnaire

I'm interested in using QUIS (http://garyperlman.com/quest/quest.cgi) but the questions about system capabilities are irrelevant for my purposes as well as the questions about screens. I'm primarily interested in terminology and learning.

Could I just use the two parts and leave out the rest? This is not for academic purposes, so I'm curious.

Comment: no it doesn't, it uses a Likert scale so you can simply add/delete or modify questions for your own purposes. However, be aware that the first part is quantitative and the second part is qualitative. These are very different measuring methods, so if you want just quantitative analysis, I'd recommend to use any Likert scale

Comment: @Devin I think your comment is more of an answer, and you should probably extend it a notch.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the questionnaire was created. Many questionnaires are just thrown together and you can do whatever you like to them - as many people who have used SUS have shown. SUS is like a raft: it won't sink but the quality of the ride is terrible.

QUIS is slightly different in that it tries to target different aspects of the system being evaluated. I think you'll be safe enough if you take sections out of QUIS and use them as chunks. I'd be wary of editing or leaving out questions from each section though.

Please note that a LIKERT scale means a collection of items which has been shown to exhibit a fairly rigorously defined set of statistical attributes - it's not just a bunch of "1 to 5" questions! Likert scales are most probably the best measurement tools we have for quantifying user experience and in such scales it is utterly foolhardy to edit or otherwise tamper with the items. A good Likert scale is like a finely-constructed piece of clockwork: tamper at your peril.